# extracting image file name from the web

Tags: python, regex, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape image information from the web and I am wondering if there is any way for me to extract the image file name. For instance if the following HTML expression is stored within the source,

```
 <img src=http://www.adbongo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/digital-bongo.jpg>,
```

I want to extract the `digital-bongo.jpg` part.

Thank you,

Comment: By using a HTML parser? I would avoid using regular expressions, certainly.

Comment: hmm...that can actually be a better idea...thanks.

Comment: is it possible that the entry might be simply `<img src="digital-bongo.jpg">` ?  or how about `<img src="http://mysite/imgejpg.jpg">` ?   if so then `src=["']?(?:.*/|/)?(.*(?:png|jpg|gif))(?:\1)?.*>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os
>>> path,file_=os.path.split('http://www.adbongo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/digital-bongo.jpg')
>>> file_
'digital-bongo.jpg'
```

Comment: ...`path,file` ? never seen such an expression before...interesting

Comment: Note file is a reserved word. file_ or some other variable name should be used instead. I can't edit because the change is under 6 characters which SO doesn't allow.

Comment: thanks @Bufke changed according to your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Using BeautifulSoup. This will pull all the links; .jpg, .gif, .png, etc. You can then use further code elaboration to get **just** jpg or gif or whatever...

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "http://www.thrashermagazine.com"
content1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content1)
for link in soup.findAll('img'):
   print link.get('src')
### or alternatively ###
for link in soup.findAll('img'):
   stuff = link.get('src')
   if '.jpg' in stuff:
      print stuff         #This will only print results with .jpg
```

*Just put *your* url in there. I used that as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Name the source of the html contents *htmlcontent* and then use **lxml** to parse the page:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> html = etree.HTML(htmlcontent)
>>> for node in html.xpath('//img/@src'):
...     print(node.text.rsplit('/', 1)[1])
```